# ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'Properties''

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Json:

```
"insertCookiesSelenium": [{ 
        "__cfduid":"asd",
        "defaultcookie":"asd",
        "usercookie":"asd" 
        }],
```

Code:

```
List<string> stringCookie = new List<string>();

dynamic cookies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(variable.Value.ToString());
IEnumerable<JProperty> property = cookies.Properties();

foreach (JProperty cookie in properties)
{
      stringCookie.Add(cookie.Name + ":" + cookie.Value);
}
```

I'm trying to get the cookies to later put it on a List. But I'm getting the next exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'Properties''
```

Been looking a while but couldn't find any solution. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) does not have `Properties` method. Try [Children](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Children.htm) method.

Comment: you loop on the wrong collection , change ``property`` to ``properties``

Comment: You are right I was looping the wrong thing haha, thanks @Sajid

Answer (score -1):

Solved by removing the [] from Json. Also in the foreach I was using the wrong property, properties.